# Apply ladspa plugin to microphone input

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio

How do I apply a ladspa plugin to my microphone input? I want to create a virtual mic with the plugin applied that I can set as my input in Discord/OBS/etc.

I tried doing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551984/apply-ladspa-plugin-to-input-microphone)

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=autotune master=alsa_output.usb-DeSheng_Electronics_Inc._XIBERIA-00.iec958-stereo plugin=autotalent label=autotalent control=440,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,5,1,0,0,0,-1,1
```

and

```
pacmd load-module module-loopback delay_msec=1
```

but it just plays my voice through my headset.